# Azure Load Balancer: Behaviour when one of a couple health probes fails

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-virtual-network

I have a load balancer in front of a set of VMs. Additionally i got several health probes with corresponding balancer rules set up.

E.g. 
A rule (with probe) for port 80 (http), onr for 443 (https) and one for 25 (smtp).

My question is:
If on VM B the 25-Port Probe fails (a couple of times so it recognizes the port on that vm as unhealthy), does the load balancer still route Port 80/443 Requests to that VM or does it generally say that VM B is unhealthy and no further traffic will be routed to that VM until its healthy again?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does those rules use the same probe? if not, I think other ports will work fine.

Comment: Yes, they are completely different probes. Each Rule has its own probe.

Comment: we can enable diagnostics for azure load balancer, in this way, we can check probe logs, please check my answer.

Answer (score -1):

For example, if your port 80 is down, and other ports are health, port 80 will not effect other service.
But if your VM CPU usage over **80%**, all probe to this VM will not health.
To monitor Azure Load Balancer probe status, we can enable **diagnostics**.
The result like this:

```
{
    "records":[
    {
        "time": "2016-01-26T10:37:46.6024215Z",
        "systemId": "32077926-b9c4-42fb-94c1-762e528b5b27",
        "category": "LoadBalancerProbeHealthStatus",
        "resourceId": "/SUBSCRIPTIONS/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXX/RESOURCEGROUPS/RG7/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.NETWORK/LOADBALANCERS/WWEBLB",
        "operationName": "LoadBalancerProbeHealthStatus",
        "properties": {
            "publicIpAddress": "40.83.190.158",
            "port": "81",
            "totalDipCount": 2,
            "dipDownCount": 1,
            "healthPercentage": 50.000000
        }
    },
    {
        "time": "2016-01-26T10:37:46.6024215Z",
        "systemId": "32077926-b9c4-42fb-94c1-762e528b5b27",
        "category": "LoadBalancerProbeHealthStatus",
        "resourceId": "/SUBSCRIPTIONS/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXX/RESOURCEGROUPS/RG7/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.NETWORK/LOADBALANCERS/WWEBLB",
        "operationName": "LoadBalancerProbeHealthStatus",
        "properties": {
            "publicIpAddress": "40.83.190.158",
            "port": "81",
            "totalDipCount": 2,
            "dipDownCount": 0,
            "healthPercentage": 100.000000
        }
    }]
}
```

Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-monitor-log) to enable it.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Thansk for your answer. now the thing is, how can i check whether the load balancer behaves the way you told me? For example the PowerShell commande tells me that Probe on Port 80 is unhealthy and on port 443 is healthy. Is there any convenient way for me to check that the 443 Port on that VM is still used by the load balancer? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Eiren can you login your VM? if yes, we can perform a network capture on this VM, if port 443 used by LB, VM will receive network package.

Comment: @Eiren Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: @Eiren can you find the load balancer behaves via network capture? Please let me know if you would like further assistance.